# iam getting error while executing code that grandchild has no attribute parent

Tags: python

```
class parent():
  def father(self):
    return ("father house")
  def father2(self):
    return ("father2 house")
class child(parent):
  def child(self):
    return ("child house")
class grandchild(child):
  def grandchild(self):
    return ("grandchild house")
```

#AttributeError: 'grandchild' object has no attribute 'parent'

Comment: Thanks for trying to provide a minimal sample. However you managed to remove the part that creates the error. Looks like the answer to a programming exercise. You could try posting the actual question

Comment: I don't know the error. Maybe what you want is `grandchild().father()`